# How to quickly migrate bookmarks toolbar and passwords from Firefox to Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, passwords, bookmarks, migration

As of lately, Firefox seems to have become much slower than Google Chrome, and this seems to be due to the presence of one or more memory leaks which slows it down considerably after it is left running for several hours or a day or so and then opening the Task Manager to visualize the sheer size of the leaks (about 1.5GB) after experiencing the slowdown.

So, what I would like to do is painlessly import all of my customized bookmarks toolbar and passwords from Firefox to Chrome without having to copy everything manually. Is there a quick way to do this, perhaps an online service or downloadable software that will somehow accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Comment: Just navigate to `chrome://settings/importData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import bookmarks from Mozilla Firefox into Google Chrome by pointing your browser to:

`chrome://settings/importData`

The same functionality is also available by clicking on Chrome's `Menu button -> Bookmarks -> Import bookmarks and settings...`. However, this creates a new folder named `Imported from Firefox` under `Menu button -> Bookmarks`. To move any bookmarks to the bookmarks toolbar just go to `Menu button -> Bookmarks -> Bookmark manager` and cut and paste any bookmarks to the Bookmarks toolbar as needed.

Regards.